# Covariance in Generics: Creating a Generic List with a Bounded Wildcard

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance

I am looking the whole day for a proper solution, bit I am fairly new to C#.
If I am right, want something similar to the Java code

```
ArrayList<IAnimalStuff<? extends Animal>> ianimals = new ArrayList<>();
```

just for C#. Or another solution when I am on the wrong way.

Detailed Scenario:
I have a base class (Animal) and multiple subclasses (e.g. Dog).

```
class Animal
{
}
class Dog : Animal
{
}
```

I create a common list of all animals, which contains objects of all kinds of different animals.

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.add(new Dog()); // and so on
```

Additionally, I have an interface and a class for each special animal derived from this interface.

```
interface IAnimalStuff<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal
{
    void doSomething(TAnimal animal);
}

public class DogStuff : IAnimalStuff<Dog>
{
    public override void doSomething(Dog animal) 
    {
    }
}
```

Now I want to manage one list with Animals and one list with AnimalStuff. When looping over all animals, I want to perform all Animalstuff in the other list which are valid for a dog. While a list of animals is no problem, I have my problems to create the other list.

```
List<IAnimalStuff<Animals>> ianimals = new List<IAnimalStuff<Animals>>();
```

Unlike in the first list, I only can add objects to this list of type

```
IAnimalStuff<Animals>
```

, but I also want to do

```
ianimals.add(GetDogStuff()); // add object of type IAnimalStuff<Dog>
```

I assumed this is valid, because Dog is a subclass of Animal. I think with the upper line of Java code this can be solved, but I did not find any solution for C#. Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Its unclear whether you have actually read about covariance in c# ? You seem to have the right terms to find the information but haven't actually mentioned it in your question... Do you just need linking to articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance or have you tried this already and not been able to get it to work?

Comment: I also found the article you mentioned, but I did not help me. As far as I understand, my approach should be possible. Maybe I cannot see the wood for the trees anymore.

Comment: C# doesn't have use-site variance, just declaration-site variance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# has declaration-site variance, not use-site variance like Java.

In C# you could do this:

```
interface IAnimalStuff<in TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal // note "in"
{
    void doSomething(TAnimal animal);
}
```

And then you could say

```
IAnimalStuff<Mammal> iasm = new MammalStuff();
IAnimalStuff<Dog> iasd = iasm;
```

Why does this work? Because `iasm.doSomething` takes any mammal, and `iasd.doSomething` will be passed only dogs, and dogs are mammals.  Notice that this is a **contravariant** conversion.

But you cannot go the other way; you can't say "dog is a mammal, therefore a dogstuff is a mammalstuff".  That mammalstuff can accept a giraffe, but a dogstuff cannot.  That would be a *covariant* conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained comment. I did some further reading on use-site variance and declaration-site variance. What I want (I think) is still a covariance conversion. Having a List of IAnimalStuff<Animal> and add all kinds of Animals to that, e.g. IAnimalStuff<Dog>. As I understand, this should be possible with out generic modifier. Unfortunately, this is only possible when my generic interface has only methods that return objects of type T, but don’t consume objects of type T, which is not the case. So I assume, I have some kind of design issue. But thank you very much nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue might be in your declaration of your list:

```
List<IAnimalStuff<Animals>> ianimals = new List<IAnimalStuff<Animals>>();
```

This is casting the "animal" of AnimalStuff to type "Animal".
Instead, try using an Interface as your base `IAnimal` and defining your collection as `IAnimalStuff<IAnimals>`. Then have `Dog` inherit from `IAnimal` and it should accomplish what you want.